CiviBooking 1.6 - DB Error
I'm running Wordpress 6.5.5 with CiviCRM 5.74.2. Civibooking installed fine. When I click on the booking menu to go into "Find Bookings" or "New Booking", I get a "DB Error: unknown error". Upon enabling debug, I get the following. Any idea on what's going wrong and how to resolve?
Type    DB_Error
Code    -1
Message DB Error: unknown error
Mode    16
UserInfo    SELECT v.id, v.label, v.value, v.option_group_id, r.weight FROM civicrm_option_value v INNER JOIN civicrm_booking_resource r ON v.option_group_id = 110 AND r.type_id = v.value AND v.is_active = 1 WHERE 1 AND r.is_unlimited = 0 ORDER BY r.weight [nativecode=1267 ** Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '=']
DebugInfo   SELECT v.id, v.label, v.value, v.option_group_id, r.weight FROM civicrm_option_value v INNER JOIN civicrm_booking_resource r ON v.option_group_id = 110 AND r.type_id = v.value AND v.is_active = 1 WHERE 1 AND r.is_unlimited = 0 ORDER BY r.weight [nativecode=1267 ** Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '=']
Civi\Core\Exception\DBQueryException: DB Error: unknown error in /mysite/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php on line 945

DB_Error: DB Error: unknown error in unknown on line unknown



In civi go to support - api3 explorer.
Choose System for the entity and utf8conversion for the action.
For parameter choose csv list of table patterns. Type in civicrm_booking%.
Click execute.


Thank you for the solution. This resolved the above errors. However, after creating a booking successfully, upon searching for all bookings to find the booking I jus created, none could be found. It seems like bookings are not being saved. I get this error:
The requested booking record does not exist (possibly the record was deleted).

I'm not familiar with the extension and not many people are going to see the comment here. It's better to post a new question since it sounds like a different issue.
